# Final MySQL Query Touches

Tags: mysql

Looking for some help with the final touches to a MySQL query....I'm so close but just cant figure out how to finish it off!

I am basically trying to work out the amounts for each customer per month which I can do, query code below:

```
select  customer_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Jan",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Feb",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "March",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "April",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "May",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "June",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 7 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "July",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 8 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Aug",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 9 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Sept",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 10 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Oct",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 11 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Nov",
    SUM(CASE WHEN month(payment_date)= 12 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Dec"         
from payment
group by customer_id

Table Layout:
 Table Name: payment
  payment_id    smallint(5) 
  customer_id   smallint(5) 
  staff_id      tinyint(3)  
  rental_id     int(11)     
  amount        decimal(5,2)    
  payment_date  datetime    
  last_update   timestamp

 OUTPUT:
 customer_id    Jan     Feb     March   April   May     June
          1     0       0.99    3.98    **0**   4.51    0

 Expected:
 customer_id    Jan     Feb       March      April      May    June
          1     0       0.99      **3.98**  **3.98**    4.51   4.51
```

However, what I cant work out is how to get the amount to equal the last amount if amount = 0 i.e if amount falls through to the else statement it needs to equal the amount of the last month rather then zero. If last month is 0 then that's fine but the amount cant be 0 if the last months amount is > 0.

NB: Query has been written against the MySQL sakila database from the phpadmin demo server for testing.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Update - Cut off the group by Statement, now added to the code above.
Update - Table structure included in the code block.

Comment: Can you post a table layout of the table you're querying?

Comment: Not sure I've understood the problem correctly, but why not using "GROUP BY month(payment_date), customer_id" ?

Comment: @Qualcuno - Im trying to carry over the payment amount to the next month if that months payment amount = 0.

Comment: @dethtron5000 - table layout added to the code block

Comment: @user3262656 I'm not sure I understand correctly. Can you provide some example data and what output you'd like to get?

Comment: @Qualcuno I've updated the code block to show current and expected output.

Comment: @user3262656 I still have some doubts. In the example case, for customer #1 in march you had amount 3.98 but payment 0? And you want that amount to be carried forward april?

Comment: There's nothing in this query that'd duplicate the April value like that. Are you sure it's not a client-side problem, using the wrong variable for displaying April?

Comment: @Qualcuno Yep, that's correct.

Comment: @ Marc B - No, its not client side. I'm wanting to update this query to carry forward the previous value if value = 0 but dont know how.

Comment: It really is better to handle this stuff at the presentation layer (assuming you have one)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.

I ended up using the presentation layer (JavaScript), thanks @Strawberry, to carry out the values over.